# Ruby gem - Requires depending on Runtime Options

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm developing a ruby gem, and my requires are a mess.

The gem is a web Scraper, which depending on the given options, uses different methods to access the web, and thus needs to require different gems. Some users may never need some gems, or any of them.

My question is, what do I put in my .gemspec:

```
 s.add_runtime_dependency #do I require all the gems here?
```

Where do I actually require the necessary gems in my code, and how do I do testing?

I don't know the conventions on this. Thanks.

*code: https://github.com/ZirconCode/Scrapah

Answer (score 0):

RubyGems provides two main “types” of dependencies: `runtime` and `development`.

Runtime dependencies are what your gem needs to work (such as `rails` needing `activesupport`).

Development dependencies are useful for when someone wants to make modifications to your gem. When you specify development dependencies, another developer can run `gem install --dev your_gem` and `RubyGems` will grab both sets of dependencies (`runtime and development`). Typical development dependencies include test frameworks and build systems.

So in Gem Specification file you can add those gems that your gems need to work

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
   s.name = "gem name"
   s.version = "2.0.0"
   s.add_runtime_dependency "daemons",
   ["= 1.1.0"]
   s.add_development_dependency "bourne",
   [">= 0"]
```